# Retrying or recovering after failed IndexWriter.Commit() in Lucene.NET

Tags: lucene.net

Our Lucene.NET index is located on a remote maching, accessible over a UNC path. For performance reasons (and following what appears to be Lucene.NET best practice) `IndexWriter` is not `Commit()`ed after each document modification, but rather once every 30 seconds.

Now, sometimes [network fails](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing) and `Commit()` errors out with an exception. I know that Lucenet.NET is "fully ACID", and as such these failures do not corrupt the index itself. What worries me is that not-yet-committed documents are lost.

Is there any recommended way of dealing with this? Can I retry `IndexWriter.Commit()` in hopes that network connectivity is restored? Or should I buffer documents in `RAMDirectory` and then merge these into `FSDirectory`, with retry semantics? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

In my implementation, I use an Oracle table.  When a document is created, a row is added to the table with a value indicating it is not indexed.  After the IndexWriter commit succeeds, I update the table to indicate it is indexed (along with some other data like indexed_date, etc.)  That way if there is any kind of failure, the document will be refound and indexed (or possibly re-indexed) when the system or connectivity is restored.  The table also opens up all kinds of reporting & audit capability that would otherwise not be available.

This might not be an option for you.  Buffering documents locally to the indexwriter would work.  Not sure why you would need retry semantics if you only looked to the local buffer for docs to index.  I think you just have to make sure you delete the document from the local buffer after the commit succeeds so you don't keep indexing it forever. ;^)